# Making a component template using angular Cli

Tags: angular, components

Suppose if I were to make a predefined component with some code in it. Then I want to use it in other projects. 
So is there a way we can make a predefined component using angular cli?

Eg. Ng g c component_name

Wherein it would create a new component with its built in code

Comment: I don't think this is possible, for this you need to make a changes in the Angular cli itself.

Comment: Have you seen angular schematics?

Comment: Yes I have, but is there any other way ?